# Standard notation for different variables?

Tags: soft-question, notation

I was wondering if there is a rule for choosing which letters to give to variables when naming or substituting them? In Gauss' Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, he uses many gothic lettering, but I haven't been able to figure out how he chooses when to use a particular letter. Is it arbitrary? What about mathematical writing in general, is there some kind of system?

Thanks.

Comment: related to [Why do mathematicians use single-letter variables?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/why-are-x-and-y-such-common-variables-in-todays-equations-how-did-their-use-or) and [Why do mathematicians use single-letter variables?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24241/why-do-mathematicians-use-single-letter-variables) question.

Comment: related to [Variable naming convention in mathematical modeling](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85963/variable-naming-convention-in-mathematical-modeling)